# how to use flash light and camera simultaneously in android?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am developing an App in which i need my flash light always on and click photos using camera in another thread. Is it possible? Any kinda help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing your own camera handling then you can look at something like this:

```
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

List<String> flashModes = params.getSupportedFlashModes();
if ( flashModes != null && flashModes.contains( Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO) ) {
    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
}
```